# How to list/show the disabled services in GCP via client library files python

Tags: python, list, google-cloud-platform, google-client, google-client-login

Kindly please help me, i am looking to list the disabled services in GCP. Expand more...
Actually i am using client library files(python) to **list** all the assets. my codes are [here](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

I am able fetch the utilized services via [this](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) codes. but is there any way to get the list of disabled services in this asset inventories/ in this code it self?? if the **listing disabled services**  not in asset, at least do we have any separate client library files(python) to get the disabled list??

[this the code i am using, u can also see [here](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) inside-->#list][Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQs2D.png)

Comment: Can you share your code? the link seems wrong

Comment: from google.cloud import asset_v1

project_resource = "projects/{}".format(project_id)
client = asset_v1.AssetServiceClient()

# Call ListAssets v1 to list assets.
response = client.list_assets(
    request={
        "parent": project_resource,
        "read_time": None,
        "asset_types": asset_types,
        "content_type": content_type,
        "page_size": page_size,
    }
)

for asset in response:
    print(asset)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere   i have atached the code image

Comment: You lost me when you talked about Disabled Services and asset. What are the relation between both? Do you want to get the assets of the disabled services? Does it not strange?

Comment: yes u r correct,  i need asset list of disabled services. Either in this code or any other client library python.

Comment: Why do you need that? The resources aren't active because of API deactivation? What's the use case?

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere  see here's the thing (I can able to fetch): Every day morning the asset code will run and take the history of all the utilized resources.( I can't able to fetch) : some of the resources in gcp are disabled. That list i can't get ,while running my asset code.       Detailed need: if resources are enabled/ utilized asset list have to print. If the resources are in unutilized/disabled, i need to print "resources are in disabled." eg- container.googleapi.com/bucket --disabled.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know how to do. I also don't know how Google can do, because the APIs are deactivated!!!

Comment: its ok bro thank u